# 14.04.3 LTS Falure to start session at the login screen

Tags: 14.04, command-line, login, users

I did a fresh install of `Ubuntu 14.04` to nights back and installed gnome desktop environment.

Everything was going great and i got everything fully customized to my liking, then ran

```
 sudo apt-get autoremove
```

and restarted.

Now when i try to login i get error

```
 failed to start session
```

I <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Fi</kbd> into the command line and tried to  run

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-session
```

then it prompts me for my password again, I enter it and it says password invalid.

I am stuck and would love to avoid re-imaging.

[pic of terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kt61m.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

According to your screen output it seems you are not entering correct usename and password . first enter your username

`pocydal-CT14 login: yourusername`  <kbd>Enter</kbd>

`Password : yourpassword`  <kbd>Enter</kbd>

then try to solve your problem using commands:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-session
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-session
sudo reboot
```

or 
it might be

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

removed your `ubuntu-desktop` so try to install that using command:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```

and 
reboot using command:

```
sudo reboot
```

or you can try

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure -a
sudo apt-get install gnome-shell ubuntu-gnome-desktop
```

Comment: Thanks, I realized what the issue was.

I am an idiot and tried to run the sudo command where it was prompting me for my user name...